# What does it mean - can be made into a double?

Tags: crankset, replacement

[Sugino Single Speed Arm Set 175mm Black 130mm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GSKV7W)

In the description it says: RD2 can be made into a double with double bolt sets.
Can I use these crankarms on my 2 front - 8 rear speed road bike?

What other parameters I should research before buying it?
(130mm BCD, 110mm bottom bracket)

Comment: Yes, if you buy two chainrings and a double bolt set. Are you replacing just the crank or the entire crankset with chainrings? If it's the latter, getting a double crankset would be simpler.

Comment: Thx for the comment. And yes I am replacing the crank only.

Comment: As a set you can find some good deals on chain rings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a JIS bottom bracket (ISO may work, but ideally you'd want JIS) of the appropriate spindle length for the correct chain line on your bike.

You'd have to buy a set of chainrings for a double and the bolts for a double chainring in order to use it as a double.